# Visual editor for MySQL views?

Tags: windows, data-visualization, mysql

Is it possible to visually (or just comfortably) edit MySQL views?

I got dbForge Studio fo MySQL, but it is able to visually edit SQL files only, not stored views.

Is there any app, which is capable to edit stored views?

**UPDATE**

My OS is windows, but I would use any if the tool is good, and the price should be reasonable no more than few hundreds of dollars.

Comment: If there's a native app, what OS should it run on? And if it's not free, what's your price limit?